# Modifying citation format of specific chapter in book - Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am currently using Biblatex for bibliography management and I would like to customize the appearance of citations. In particular, I have

```
\cite[Ch.~3, Sec.~3.2]{some_book}
```

which outputs something like

[image]

while I would like to get something like

[image]

Is there a way to modify the `\cite` command to get this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `numeric` style: `\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how do you want to print the `prenote` information you can define two different commands.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%\myciteA
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myciteA}
{\bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\usebibmacro{cite}\bibclosebracket}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

%\myciteB
\renewbibmacro*{Bprenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}\addspace}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myciteB}
{\usebibmacro{Bprenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

With prenote inside the brackets:

\myciteA[Ch.~3, Sec.~3.2]{knuth:ct}

\myciteA[see][Ch.~3, Sec.~3.2]{knuth:ct}

\bigskip

With prenote outside the brackets:

\myciteB[see][Ch.~3, Sec.~3.2]{knuth:ct}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I also wanted to redefine the ```\cite``` command, so I just wrote ```\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}```. Is this the way to do it or do I need to use something like ```renewbibmacro{cite}```?

Comment: No, that is the right way